# PEAR installation without go-pear.bat on windows

Tags: php, installation, pear

I have installed PHP 5.3.3 on my machine without pear. 
But now i want to install on my machine without removing the existing configuration. 
In there any way to manually update PEAR without  go-pear.bat on windows ?

THANK YOU ALL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy pear lib in your system from old installation

you use PHP ? or wamp or xampp ?

Comment: i have just php. No wamp or xampp 
Also i do not have any pear installed on my machine

Comment: i guess apt is with linux and not with windows

Comment: oh you are windows ... sorry i think the only way is go-pear.bat ... maybe you can install in other machine and copy file is not bad .

Comment: Well i guess go-pear.bat is the only best way to install pear. There are other ways but they lack more information 
THANK U  Efazati...........

Though i have marked the answer right, Please view the comments for right answer